# Routing error in heroku app after deployment with git push command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am at chapter 3 of Michael Hartl's tutorial but when I do `git push heroku master` and it says that it has been deployed to heroku successfully but when I go to the url: http://young-thicket-2043.herokuapp.com/ it says that the app cannot be seen.

I've checked out `heroku logs` and this was given:

```
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462137+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462132+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462138+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462148+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462150+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462151+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462158+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462159+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462161+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462162+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462164+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462165+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462167+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462170+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462171+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462173+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462174+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462176+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462177+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462194+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462179+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462184+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462185+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462187+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462181+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462183+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462191+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462192+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462188+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.462190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-07-02T08:07:16.781513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-thicket-2043.herokuapp.com request_id=f65ad084-f721-4a4c-8f99-bdd1938d4dd4 fwd="192.122.131.37" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-07-02T08:16:35.325747+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=young-thicket-2043.herokuapp.com request_id=4fc6cfec-39d8-4a2c-ac04-09013042ca7b fwd="192.122.131.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=520ms status=404 bytes=1616
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319865+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319873+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319870+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-07-02T08:16:35.217481+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 192.122.131.37 at 2014-07-02 08:16:35 +0000
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319876+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319891+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319878+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319892+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319880+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319881+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319921+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319883+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319886+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319884+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.225563+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 192.122.131.37 at 2014-07-02 08:16:35 +0000
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319919+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321135+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319923+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319887+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321127+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319897+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319894+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321137+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321145+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321134+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321138+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319901+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319899+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319898+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319925+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319889+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.319924+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321141+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321161+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321140+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321130+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321149+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321131+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321148+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321155+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321162+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321142+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321154+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321152+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321156+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321159+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-07-02T08:16:35.321163+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T08:16:35.764555+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-thicket-2043.herokuapp.com request_id=ca661424-73d7-4799-8ad7-5fed577fd9c2 fwd="192.122.131.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=52ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-07-02T08:16:40.905460+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db` by huicheese@gmail.com
2014-07-02T08:16:44.546386+00:00 heroku[run.7223]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-02T08:16:44.833806+00:00 heroku[run.7223]: Awaiting client
2014-07-02T08:16:55.930802+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by huicheese@gmail.com
2014-07-02T08:16:59.934050+00:00 heroku[run.6502]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-02T08:16:59.814001+00:00 heroku[run.6502]: Awaiting client
2014-07-02T08:17:16.236553+00:00 heroku[run.7223]: State changed from up to complete
2014-07-02T08:17:16.224283+00:00 heroku[run.7223]: Process exited with status 128
2014-07-02T08:17:14.840989+00:00 heroku[run.7223]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-07-02T08:17:31.040049+00:00 heroku[run.6502]: State changed from up to complete
2014-07-02T08:17:29.816567+00:00 heroku[run.6502]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-07-02T08:17:31.023583+00:00 heroku[run.6502]: Process exited with status 128
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: you don't have any root route setup

Comment: @Mandeep sorry for being a noob but what do u mean by root route setup? is it in routes.rb i have to declare root :to => "pages#show"

Comment: @huicheese if you have a new problem, you should ask a new question, not tack on an additional question once your original problem was solved.

Comment: Duplicate of [ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches \[GET\] "/"):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194386/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get)

Comment: @Cupcake OH. right. i am sorry. i'll take note of that next time! thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your logs you can see

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/")
```

Which basically means that you don't have any root route setup in your **routes.rb**. Inside your routes.rb add this line:

```
root 'pages#show'
```

By writing this you are setting your root route to **`Page Controllers show action`**