# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-api

I have a `Rails API` which is being accessed by my `React` client-side. Every time the react application is loaded it makes a `get` request to the `API` for the path `/` and this raises the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/"
```

Although this doesn't really affect user interaction on the application but I would still like to remove this.

My API has a normal path of `<url>/backend-api/v2.3.3/..`

I think this can be fixed by adding a `root` path on the routes but considering that the initially loaded pages on React are static and don't really need to make an API call, how can I catch this initial `GET /` and prevent the error from being raised?

Comment: I think preventing React sending request to `/` path will be correct approach. Approach to hide error on server side - will be workaround which just hide symptoms of originally wrong behaviour.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194386/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this the routes.rb file under the api scope:

```
get '/', to: proc { [200, {}, ['']] }
```