# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/contacts"): Rails + React

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, ruby-on-rails-7

I am creating a hybrid architecture single page website using Rails 7.1.2 and React on the Frontend. Long story short I am using Vite and set up my frontend using an api using my contacts_controller. Api was working fine, I changed some settings and now all pages work except the one pulling all contacts from the api. I've tried any close solution on this and am still getting this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/contacts"):
```

I have routes set up in a AppRoutes.jsx file under frontend/src/components and this was working just fine before and this is my vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

i've also tried many versions of routes.rb but this is most recent. I've also tried other suggestions from SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194386/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get) but not getting any results. Any help would be great!! Many thanks in advance

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Devise routes for authentication
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }

  # API routes within the /api/v1 namespace
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :contacts
    end
  end

  # Health check route
  get "up" => "rails/health#show", as: :rails_health_check
  
  # Serve React application from the Rails public directory
  # for any routes not matched above
  get '*path', to: 'application#fallback_index_html', constraints: ->(request) {
    !request.xhr? && request.format.html?
  }
  
  # The root path routed to fallback_index_html to serve the React app
  root 'application#fallback_index_html'
end
```

I am trying to set up a 'contacts' page where a user can see all contacts that were submitted via a contact me form.

Comment: Might be worth commenting - I am also using devise